# Script doesn't work with "&"-symbol

Tags: javascript, if-statement, symbols

Noticed that everything in my if-statements with an "&"-symbol doesn't work. How do I fix this?

```
if(id == 'EX&219'){
//do someting
}
```

This doesn't work. So happy for any help :)

Comment: [Yes it works](http://jsfiddle.net/gs2Wh/)

Comment: The if statement is obviously working. Maybe it's the value from the database that's returned in a form that's not expected. Can you post what `console.log(JSON.stringify(id))` or `alert(JSON.stringify(id))` prints?

Answer (score 1):

Working Perfect

```
var id = 'EX&219';
if(id == 'EX&219'){
    alert("equals");
} else {
    alert("not equal");
}
```

[Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/gs2Wh/1/)

Comment: I don't get it to work with any answer... My values if fetched from database and is clearly like this when i write it out "AS-S&V-SA". But when i use it in if-statement it don't work. It is "-" and "&" that fails everything i guess... @Naveen

Comment: @PeterP you are getting exactly AS-S&V-SA or "AS-S&V-SA" or both as different AS-S and V-SA? It is also working fine http://jsfiddle.net/gs2Wh/2/

Comment: Well some of my id's looks like "AS-S&V-SA" as one id. Weird that is doesn't work... @Naveen

Comment: sure, just a sec @Naveen

Comment: I noticed this. when i save my database data to variables it doesn't work. But when I save it like "var ID = 'AS-S&V-SA'" it works... @Naveen

Comment: And it only fails when "&"symbol is in the id :P @Naveen

Comment: @PeterP once check id value in alert, like http://jsfiddle.net/gs2Wh/3/ and post id value now

Comment: Well i have done echos and document.write's and alert and it equals the text I put into my if-statement. It is very weird that it doesn't work. I mean, its just text :/ Everything without "&" works fine ^^ @Naveen

Comment: and alert prints exactly?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. It works for all other hundreds of id's that not contains "&". @Naveen

Comment: @PeterP what i am asking is, id prints what value in alert? comment here that value.

Comment: It prints the exact value that i write in my "if-statement"... The real id that doesnt work is "LRM-Q&P" and other id's with "-" works, so must be the "&". @Naveen

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "*everything in my if-statements with an "&"-symbol doesn't work*" ?

Try this

```
if(id == 'EX'+String.fromCharCode(38)+'219'){
//do someting
}
```

38 is the char code for '&' character, if your don't want the '&' to appear in your statment.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromCharCode.asp

Comment: Well when my id's are fetched from database and saved into script variables and contains "&" it doesn't work in if statement. But if it not contains "&" it works perfectly fine.